# ¿Cómo puedo traer los demás filas de una BD de SQL Server usando sqlsrv_fetch_array()?

Tags: php

Espero que puedan ayudarme, estoy haciendo unos ejercicios de practicas en php ya que soy nuevo en ello y lo necesito para formar parte de mi CV.

Estoy viendo que al usar sqlsrv_fetch_array() solo me trae un 1 fila de registros en una tabla en mi BD, estoy usando SQLServer y quiero que me despliegue todos, aquí el código:

```
    <?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $serverName = "(Localdb)\serverDatilo"; //serverName\instanceName
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"testdb");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName,$connectionInfo);
    if( $conn === false ) {
       die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $sql = "SELECT id, nombrenacion, nombremandatario FROM paises";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultado = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Lo voy a desplegar en un datatable pero antes necesito obtener todos los registros de la tabla en cuestión, ya usé:

```
    while ($row = $resultado){
         print_r($row);
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
```

Y sé que me regresa una y otra vez un mismo row mas de una vez pero no me sale los demás.

Espero que puedan darme otros ejemplos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te diré como lo he implementado yo en un script que tengo y que funciona perfectamente:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $serverName = "(Localdb)\serverDatilo"; //serverName\instanceName
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"testdb");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName,$connectionInfo);
    if( $conn === false ) {
       die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $sql = "SELECT id, nombrenacion, nombremandatario FROM paises";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));
    $rows = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);

    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo '<pre>';
            print_r($row);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
```

Puedes leer mas sobre los [Tipos de Cursores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/cursor-types-sqlsrv-driver?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16)

PD: Usa nombres en **camelCase** o **snake_case**, pero ese tipo de nombres "nombremandatario" no está bien implementado, por lo general se debe usar **snake_case**...

Comment: Excelente bro, funcionó, y sí tienes razón sobre camelCase y esos, es que seguí el tutorial al pie de la letra y no me fijé de eso, toca corregir jeje gracias por tu respuesta y saludos, que tengas y un lindo día.